# Can not verify contract on etherscan.io "Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI"

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, remix

I'm trying to verify my deployed contract on etherscan.io

However I get the following error:

"rror! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI"

I'm not putting in an ABI because my constructor doesn't have any values or arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my contract code:

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

// deploying contract on account 0x80A3bA6F52D63aFF73cA582343C2F67046DcEC6f
contract PayCheck {
    //List all the empolyees ethereum payment addresses in an array.
    address[] employees = [0x9391ea51c338410B6603e38dD14C00a1b218C8d5, 0x9391ea51c338410B6603e38dD14C00a1b218C8d5 ];

    //Set a variable that trackes the total recieved to the contract, starting with 0.
    uint totalReceived = 0;

    //Create a dictionary that tracks how much as been withdrawn to each ethereum address.
    mapping (address => uint) withdrawnAmounts;

    //This function updates the total amount that's been sent to the contract 
    function PayCheck() payable {
        updateTotal();
    }
    function () payable {
        updateTotal();
    }
    // This is an internal function that updates the total amount that's been sent to the contract.
    function updateTotal() internal {
        totalReceived += msg.value;
    }

    //Here is a modifier that ensures only people in the empolyees list that execute the withdraw function.
    modifier canWidthdraw() {
        bool contains = false;

    //A simple for loop that check if they are in the empolyee list before it's aloud to execute the function this modifier is assigned to.    
        for(uint i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if(employees[i] == msg.sender) {
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        require(contains);
        _;
    }

    // Function that calculates what the user can withdraw and to where.
    function withdraw() canWidthdraw {
        uint amountAllocated = totalReceived/employees.length;
        uint amountWithdrawn = withdrawnAmounts[msg.sender];
        uint amount = amountAllocated - amountWithdrawn;
        withdrawnAmounts[msg.sender] = amountWithdrawn + amount;
        if (amount > 0) {
            msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the compiler and set optimization to match the method you used to compile the bytecode that is actually deployed. Here, `^` confuses matters because it could be anything 0.4 or higher.

You can test your actual compiler, but the method to do so will depend on what you used. For example, `solc version` or `truffle version`. Etherscan is going to compile the pasted source as instructed and compare to the bytecode it actually finds on the chain at the address you specified. When there's a match, it will record it and indicate the source you pasted is legit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yay I did it, Thanks Rob, I was using solidity remix, and the way I checked the details of the compiler, and worked out I deployed it using version: 0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05 I simply changed it to the correct compiler and it worked. Thanks Rob and Merry Xmas!